# Help in setting up Xbox controller (Wired) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xbox-360

I'm following this >> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xbox360Controller
and am not understanding the 'Creating a Makefile' part. Should I make a new document file named 'Makefile' and paste this inside >>

```
KERNEL_PATH?=/usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)

EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I$(shell pwd)

obj-m:=xpad.o

all:
        $(MAKE) modules -C $(KERNEL_PATH) SUBDIRS=$(shell pwd)

install:
        cp -f xpad.ko /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/joystick
```

cause if yes, when i use make command then this error shows >>

```
Makefile:11: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

sorry for being a noob ;) what am I supposed to do now? OR am i doing it all wrong?