# How do I get my Xbox360 controller to work in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: games, xbox-360, joystick

I'm trying to play The W​alking D​ead on Ubuntu 12.10 with my Xbox360 controller like I do in Windows. The thing is the game start and only lets my use the mouse and keyboard. In windows when the control is unplugged it start like that and when it's plugged in it's start in the Xbox360 mode (different bottons and so on).

I tried installing the Xbox360 driver [as shown here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142393/help-in-setting-up-xbox-controller-wired-in-ubuntu-12-04) but the ppa is missing.

I also tried installing [Jtest](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/08/how-to-install-and-configure-xbox-360.html) and it recognizes the controller and all, but still I can't use it in the game.

Comment: Also try qjoypad. This answer might help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140617/how-do-i-use-a-gamepad/225484#225484

Comment: Here is my explanation how to fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438422/22-04-the-xbox-controller-of-wine-has-a-mistake-how-to-fix/

Answer (score 4):

Your problem here isn't with Ubuntu or The W​alking Dead, it's with Wine. That's the compatibility layer you're using to be able to play a Windows game on a Linux operating system.

[I've already asked about this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102592/joysticks-and-gamepads-in-wine) but unfortunately Wine just doesn't support joysticks in any meaningful at the moment. I'm sure there are some edge cases but there you go.

There is one workaround that I know of that may work for some things: Mapping the joystick into keyboard controls. It's messy as hell, and you lose the resolution of the sticks but for some things, this will be enough. You'll need to use [`xboxdrv`](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/) for this, so blocking the built-in `xpad` module may be necessary.

Here's an example:

```
xboxdrv --trigger-as-button --ui-axismap x2=ABS_Z,y2=ABS_RZ --ui-buttonmap A=BTN_B,B=BTN_X,X=BTN_A,TR=BTN_THUMBL,TL=BTN_MODE,GUIDE=BTN_THUMBR
```

I've lifted that almost verbatim from [a thread on the xboxdrv forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xboxdrv/wgY0sp-drD8). It's targeting Rage so in all likelihood it's not going to be perfect for you and you'll need to play around with the mappings.

Comment: I tried using it in Team Fortress 2 and it detects it and all, but the right sticks only moves horizontally. [Here are the details](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236185/how-can-i-calibrate-my-xbox360-controller-in-ubuntu-12-10)
Thanks for your aswear!