# How can I calibrate my Xbox360 controller in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, games, gamepad, xbox-360, joystick

I was trying to play The Walking Dead Game with my Xbox360 controller and it didn't work, [in this same site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235849/how-do-i-get-my-xbox360-controller-to-work-in-ubuntu-12-10) a helpful user told me it was a wine problem and not the driver or the game. So, I tried using the controller in Team Fortress2 for Ubuntu Steam, it detects the controller and all, but right stick (the one for aiming) only moves horizontaly, and not vertically.

I tried a software called "jstest-gtk" and it confirmed the problem, the right stick doesn't move in the correct axis like the left one. In the game it only moves horizontally but in the software it only moves vertically. When I move the stick vertickally, the pointer in jstest only moves a little, also vertically. When I move the stick horizontally, the pointer in jstest moves a lot, also vertically (as you can see in the video). I thick that is the problem. The left stick moves perfect.

I know it's very difficult to explain in words so I uploaded [this video](http://youtu.be/m94BCfiC_gk) to Youtube. I hope it help to figure out what the problem is. I only know the game is not the problem, because it shows the same pattern of the right-stick as jstest-gtk, and that the controller isn't either, because it work perfectly on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've found the answer by now, but if not...

using jstest-gtk you need to hit the mapping tool and move ABS_Z to right above ABS_RZ. 
To get this to set itself when you plug it in:

```
sudo jscal-store /dev/input/js0 
(replace js0 with your joystick, you can see which it is in jstest-gtk)
```

you'll need the joystick package installed for this.